# PyQt5: gridlayout spacing issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgridlayout, cellspacing

I am a newbie in PyQt5. I'm trying to create a cell grid with a button at the bottom:

```
 g = QGridLayout(window)     
 for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        b = QPushButton()
        g.addWidget(b, i, j, 1, 1)
 g.addWidget(QPushButton("Last move"), N+4, N//2)
```

And this is what I get:

[image: screenshot]

As you see, the button spoils everything. How to can I get rid of the space between the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge the cells together in the bottom row, so the button doesn't get a column of its own:

```
    button = QPushButton("Last move")
    g.addWidget(button, N, 0, 1, N, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

The third and fourth arguments set the row and column span of the cell. If you want the button to stretch the full width, omit the last argument.

Comment: thank you! that solves my problem but I don't quiet understand how the button affects the cells.

Comment: @theluckyemil. Your original example creates a 6x5 grid, with the button being added to the middle column. That column has to stretch to take the button, which creates all that empty space on its right-hand side. Merging the columns of the bottom row means the button doesn't get added to middle column of the block of cells above. Instead, it gets a separate area of the grid-layout to itself.